# Creating a many to many relationship with uploaded data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I've looked around the internet, but most the examples I've come across only explain how to form the relationship with user input. What i'm looking for is something like below:

Table 1

```
      -----ID--------NAME-----------
           1     Bill Smithers 
           2     Steve oneguy
           3     Mike Michaels 
      -------------------------------
```

Table 2

```
      ----ID------Number--------charges------
          1    111-111-1111      $1.01
          2    111-111-1111      $2.00
          3    222-222-2222      $3.00
          4    333-333-3333      $ .50
          5    111-111-1111      $2.50
          6    222-222-2222      $1.75
      ----------------------------------------
```

Result after joining the tables would look like this:

```
     -----Name-------------Number-------------Charges-----
        Bill Smithers     111-111-1111        $1.01
        Bill Smithers     111-111-1111        $2.00
        Steve Oneguy      222-222-2222        $3.00
        Mike Michaels     333-333-3333        $ .50
        Bill Smithers     111-111-1111        $2.50
        Steve Oneguy      222-222-2222        $1.75
    -------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I know there needs to be a third table that holds the relation, but without manually entering the relationship in, i'm not sure how I would get the two tables to match up accordingly. I would assume the third table needs to ultimately look like this:

```
        -----Name_ID-----------DATA_ID---------
                1                1
                1                2
                2                3
                3                4
                1                5
                2                6
        ---------------------------------------
```

The source data already comes in looking like this:

```
     -----Name-------------Number-------------Charges-----
        Bill Smithers     111-111-1111        $1.01
        Bill Smithers     111-111-1111        $2.00
        Steve Oneguy      222-222-2222        $3.00
        Mike Michaels     333-333-3333        $ .50
        Bill Smithers     111-111-1111        $2.50
        Steve Oneguy      222-222-2222        $1.75
    -------------------------------------------------------
```

but I want to add some optimization because the table is eventually going to become much larger.

Comment: Sorry - can you clarify what you're actually asking? Yes, for Many-to-Many, the common solution is a joining table; if your source data doesn't provide a match, you will have to enter it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your application should have the data in a single glob, correct? Each time a person adds an amount, they use their phone number? In this way, you can have your application submit the data for person, then phone/payment, getting ID's back from both, which it can then send to insert into the third table. Alternately, you could submit all pieces into an SP and have the SP use the output IDs because your application doesn't care.

This isn't how I'd arrange it (as phone numbers can change for a given person, making them poor identifiers), but if you are looking for a solution, have each instance passed to the SP, and have the SP do the duplicate checking for name, inserting for the donation, and finally (using both IDs) setup the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying that you get a table Source from which you derive/extract/distill Table1, Table2 and Table3 such that when you combine/reassemble them to Result it is equal to Source.

Source/Result can have duplicate rows because the same Name, Number & Cost could appear multiple times. To query relationally a table should be designed to have no duplicates. Otherwise, query results don't mean the straightforward things they mean when there are no duplicates. It is also much more complicated to talk about such lists of rows rather than sets of rows. Standard SQL JOIN isn't even defined to give any particular results when there are duplicates input.

Each Source/Result row corresponds to a call. You may actually be intending to have more call property columns so that there are no duplicates. Otherwise you can get a unique call ID by [Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html). I will refer to a table value Call that looks like Source/Result with an an added unique call ID column. You really should use Call instead of Source/Result.

- Call is the rows where "call with id [ID] was by the person named [Name] to number [Number] with charge [Charge]"
- Table1 is the rows where "[ID] identifies name [Name]".
- Table2 is the rows where "call [ID] was to number [Number] with charge [Charge]".
- Table3 is the rows where "the person named by the name with id [Name_ID] made call [DATA_ID]".

When we insert Numbers and Costs from Source into Table2 a new ID value will be generated by auto_increment. We can consider that value to be the ID value for the corresponding row in Call.

When we insert corresponding Names from Source into Table1 that are not already in it a new ID will be generated by auto_increment for each (new) name.

By [Obtaining Auto-Increment Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html) we can then insert corresponding ID and DATA_ID pairs into Table3.

Now let's reconstitute Call and Source/Result. Recall that Call is the rows where

- "call with id [ID] was by the person named [Name] to number [Number] with charge [Charge]"

So Call is the rows where

- "there exists a Name_ID where
      [Name_ID] identifies name [Name]
  AND the person named by the name with id [Name_ID] made call [DATA_ID]
  AND call [DATA_ID] was to number [Number] with charge [Charge]"

So Call is (by substituting Table1, Table2 and Table3 for their predicates/statements per the bullets above)

```
SELECT DATA_ID,Name,Number,Charge
FROM Table1 n
JOIN Table3 t ON n.ID=Name_ID
JOIN Table2 d ON DATA_ID=d.ID
```

We get Result from Call via

```
-- keep duplicates
SELECT Name,Number,Cost
FROM Call
```

So Result is

```
-- keep duplicates
SELECT Name,Number,Charge
FROM Table1 n
JOIN Table3 t ON n.ID=Name_ID
JOIN Table2 d ON DATA_ID=d.ID
```